# How to pipe ppm data into ffmpeg from blender frameserver with while loop in PowerShell

Tags: loops, powershell, ffmpeg, pipe, blender

Blender 2.6 manual features this little `sh` script for encoding a video from the Blender frameserver via `ffmpeg`. It works great on Windows with Cygwin, but only without `-hwaccel` hardware acceleration flag.

```sh
#!/bin/sh
BLENDER=http://localhost:8080
OUTPUT=/tmp/output.ogv
eval `wget ${BLENDER}/info.txt -O - 2>/dev/null |
    while read key val ; do
        echo R_$key=$val  
    done`
i=$R_start
{
    while [ $i -le $R_end ] ; do
       wget ${BLENDER}/images/ppm/$i.ppm -O - 2>/dev/null
       i=$(($i+1))
    done
} | ffmpeg -vcodec ppm -f image2pipe -r $R_rate -i pipe:0 -b 6000k -vcodec libtheora $OUTPUT
wget ${BLENDER}/close.txt -O - 2>/dev/null >/dev/null
```

I'd like to encode my videos from Blender's in Windows with `-hwaccel dxva2` which works with PowerShell. I've begun converting the script to PowerShell but I have run into one last problem. I am having difficulty replicating this part of the script in PowerShell.

```sh
i=$R_start
{
    while [ $i -le $R_end ] ; do
       wget ${BLENDER}/images/ppm/$i.ppm -O - 2>/dev/null
       i=$(($i+1))
    done
} | ffmpeg -vcodec ppm -f image2pipe -r $R_rate -i pipe:0 -b 6000k -vcodec libtheora $OUTPUT
```

Below is my conversion to PowerShell.

```bsh
echo "gathering data";
$blender = "http://localhost:8080";
$output = "C:\Users\joel\Desktop\output.mp4";
$webobj = wget $blender"/info.txt";
$lines = $webobj.Content -split('[\r\n]') | ? {$_};
$info = @{};
foreach ($line in $lines) {
    $lineinfo = $line -split('[\s]') | ? {$_};
    $info[$lineinfo[0]] = $lineinfo[1];
}
echo $info;
[int]$end = [convert]::ToInt32($info['end'],10);
[int]$i = [convert]::ToInt32($info['start'],10);
$video="";
( while ($i -le $end) {
    $frame = wget $blender"/images/ppm/"$i".ppm" > $null;
    echo $frame.Content > $null;
    $i++;
} ) | ffmpeg -hwaccel dxva2 -vcodec ppm -f image2pipe -r $info['rate'] -i pipe:0 -b 6000k -vcodec libx264 $output;
```

This is the piece I'm having trouble with. I'm not quite sure what the proper syntax is to pipe the data into the `ffmpeg` command in the same way as the bash script above.

```bsh
( while( $i -le $end ) {
    $frame = wget $blender"/images/ppm/"$i".ppm" > $null;
    echo $frame.Content > $null;
    $i++;
} ) | ffmpeg -hwaccel dxva2 -vcodec ppm -f image2pipe -r $info['rate'] -i pipe:0 -b 6000k -vcodec libx264 $output;
```

Here is the output:

```
PS C:\Users\joel\Desktop> .\encode.ps1
gathering data

Name                           Value
----                           -----
rate                           30
height                         720
ratescale                      1
end                            57000
width                          1280
start                          1
while : The term 'while' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function,
script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path
was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At C:\Users\joel\Desktop\encode.ps1:15 char:3
+ ( while ($i -le $end) {
+   ~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (while:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

Comment: I'm not sure why you you need a pipe there? just do:
while () {save results to variable}
and then do your stuff;
because while won't work within ()

Comment: I'm not sure what's happening in the bash script with its pipe loop, but it does not download all 50,000+ ppm frames into one object then start ffmpeg. It appears to just load the first one, then ffmpeg starts encoding.

Answer (score 0):

Your (PowerShell) `while` loop doesn't feed anything into `ffmpeg` because you suppress the regular output by redirecting it to `$null`.

If you compare the body of that loop

```bsh
$frame = wget $blender"/images/ppm/"$i".ppm" > $null;
echo $frame.Content > $null;
$i++;
```

to the body of the second (bash) `while` loop

```sh
wget ${BLENDER}/images/ppm/$i.ppm -O - 2>/dev/null
i=$(($i+1))
```

you'll notice that the bash version only redirects STDERR output (`2>/dev/null`), not STDOUT output. Also the `()` that you put around the (PowerShell) `while` loop only work for simple expressions. For complex expressions you need to use the [subexpression operator](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847732.aspx) (`$()`).

To fix this just drop the redirection from the PowerShell statements and use `$(...)` instead of `(...)`.

With that said, there are some other improvements to be made to the rest of your code. For one, the `info.txt` download and hashtable creation could be streamlined like this:

```bsh
$info = @{}
(wget "$blender/info.txt").Content -split '[\r\n]+' |
    Where-Object { $_ } |
    ForEach-Object {
        $key, $val = $_ -split '\s', 2
        $info[$key] = $val
    }
```

Your second loop would also work better as a `ForEach-Object` loop, with input generated via the range operator (`..`):

```bsh
$start = [int]$info['start']
$end   = [int]$info['end']
$start..$end | ForEach-Object {
    (wget "$blender/images/ppm/$_.ppm").Content
} | ffmpeg ...
```